# Unable to use cdef function in std::sort as comparison function

Tags: c++, macos, cython

The code below is from [this file](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/epic2/blob/ffd75cd4ef52b040e133d00c87053bb4c30b5c0a/epic2/src/read_bam.pyx). It compiles correctly on Linux, but fails to compile on OS X.

I want to sort a vector of self-defined intervals:

```
stdsort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), compare_start_end)
```

My comparison function is the following:

```
cdef uint32_t compare_start_end(interval lhs, interval rhs):
  if (lhs.start < rhs.start):
    return <uint32_t> 1
  elif (rhs.start < lhs.start):
      return <uint32_t> 0
  elif (lhs.end < rhs.end):
      return <uint32_t> 1
  else:
    return <uint32_t> 0
```

The error I get is the following:

```
In file included from epic2/src/read_bam.cpp:651:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:4117:5: error: no matching function for call to '__sort'
    __sort<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __comp);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
epic2/src/read_bam.cpp:3305:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::sort<std::__1::__wrap_iter<__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval *>, unsigned int (__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)>'
      requested here
      std::sort<std::vector<__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval> ::iterator,uint32_t (__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)>(__pyx_v_intervals.begin(), __pyx_v_intervals.end(), __pyx_f_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_compare_start_end);
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:3914:1: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned int (*)(__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)' to 'unsigned int
      (&)(__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)' for 3rd argument; dereference the argument with *
__sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last, _Compare __comp)
^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

The problem seems to be one of types.

I have

```
'unsigned int (*)(__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)'
```

but my function expects

```
unsigned int (&)(__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)
```

The hint is to try to dereference the third argument, but this does not work.

```
stdsort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), dereference(compare_start_end))
```

Instead, it errors with

```
Compiling epic2/src/read_bam.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing epic2/src/read_bam.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        intervals = dereference(it).second
        five_ends = intvec()

        if drop_duplicates:

            stdsort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), dereference(compare_start_end))
                                                       ^
```

Do you have any advice? Ps. the above compiles on linux, but not on macOS, so the code is brittle.

---

## System info

macOS Mojave, 10.14.6 (18G87)

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

## Minimal reproducible example

```
# minimal_example.pyx
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

ctypedef struct interval:
    uint32_t start
    uint32_t end

ctypedef vector[uint32_t] intvec
ctypedef vector[interval] interval_vector


cdef uint32_t compare_start_end(interval lhs, interval rhs):
  if (lhs.start < rhs.start):
    return <uint32_t> 1
  elif (rhs.start < lhs.start):
      return <uint32_t> 0
  elif (lhs.end < rhs.end):
      return <uint32_t> 1
  else:
    return <uint32_t> 0


cdef test(interval_vector intervals):
    stdsort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), compare_start_end)
```

Compile with:

```
folder_with_Python_h="/mnt/work/endrebak/software/anaconda/include/python3.7m/"
cython --cplus minimal_example.pyx
gcc -I $folder_with_Python_h  -c minimal_example.cpp -o minimal_example.o -Ofast -Wall -std=c++11
```

Same error message pops up on macOS, but not linux.

Other commands I have tried, giving the same results:

```
g++  -I /Users/endrebakkenstovner/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/ -stdlib=libc++  -c minimal_example.cpp -o minimal_example.o -Ofast -Wall
gcc  -I /Users/endrebakkenstovner/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/  -c minimal_example.cpp -o minimal_example.o -Ofast -Wall -lc++
```

## Attempts to change the Cython code

Adding these lines before cdef test

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void stdsort(...)
```

results in (on both linux and macOS)

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void stdsort(...)


cdef test(interval_vector intervals):
    stdsort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), compare_start_end)
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

minimal_example.pyx:30:11: ambiguous overloaded method
```

Adding "sort" at the end of stdsort(...) as per the comment results in (both linux and macOS):

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
  else:
    return <uint32_t> 0


cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void stdsort(...) "sort"
                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Apple used to provide an ancient version of the C++ runtime that pretends to be C++11. What version of OS X, and what version of Clang? You should probably supply [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah try compiling with `-lc++` instead of `-lstdc++` (which might be the default depending on your deployment target).  The newer C++ runtime is 10.7+ so you might need to consider that when building.

Comment: You probably just need it on the linker step then.

Comment: Try using `-stdlib=libc++` ... and instead of `gcc` try `g++`...

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that Cython insists on telling it the template arguments. Instead of cimporting sort, can you try: `cdef extern from ”<algorithm>" namespace "std": void stdsort(...) "sort"`. Essentially the difference is that Cython will let C++ figure out the template arguments.

Comment: I'L'I has the option I was thinking of.

Comment: @DavidW If I remove the `cimport` of `sort` and reduce your suggestion to `cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void sort(...)` it seems to work on both linux and macOS. Perhaps you could add it as an answer with an explanation?

Comment: @DavidW I have the same problem with unique from `<algorithm>`. What should the type be imported as here? It cannot be void and I cannot find an import for the iterator C++ type...

Comment: @TheUnfunCat Will do... I'm not sure about unique, but I'll see if I can figure it out

Comment: I'll create a new question for that. That one will be about how to use iterator as a type in Cython :)

Comment: Are you trying to do the 3 argument version of unique?

Comment: It's OK - it isn't a huge extension to the question. If I can answer it I'll just tack it on here

Comment: Yes, I am actually sorting just to remove duplicates. And I need the three arg version for it to understand and know how to compare my intervals :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that Cython insists on specifying the template arguments. Instead of generating C code that looks like:

```
std::sort(__pyx_v_intervals.begin(), __pyx_v_intervals.end(), __pyx_f_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_compare_start_end);
```

it generates

```
std::sort<std::vector<__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval> ::iterator,uint32_t (__pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval, __pyx_t_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_interval)>(__pyx_v_intervals.begin(), __pyx_v_intervals.end(), __pyx_f_5epic2_3src_8read_bam_compare_start_end);
```

Generally in C++ it's better to let C++ figure out the template arguments. In this case I think Cython has probably messed up the function pointer argument.

The solution is to not tell Cython that you have a template function. The involves re-wrapping the functions yourself rather than using Cython's libcpp wrappers. One option is to just specify all the types - the types don't have to match *exactly* but have to be close enough that Cython thinks it can pass the right arguments:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithn>" namespace "std":
    # code is untested because this isn't the solution I used...
    void sort(vector[interval].iterator, vector[interval].iterator,
              uint32_t (*)(interval, interval))
```

I prefer just using `...`. This was designed to wrap C varargs functions like `printf` where you can pass anything but it works perfectly well here too:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void sort(...)
    # to rename to stdsort do
    void stdsort "sort"(...)
```

The end result is that Cython stops trying to tell C++ what the template arguments should be.

---

`std::unique` is a little more complicated since it has a return type. Therefore Cython needs to know at least one template argument. Fortunately I'm pretty sure that only the last argument is causing problems, so you can safely tell Cython about the first argument being a template:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    Iter unique[Iter](Iter, Iter, ...)
```