# Cython: giving cdef extern functions the type iterator from C++

Tags: cython

I have the following code where all works well except the `cdef extern` of `unique` (*):

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

ctypedef struct interval:
    uint32_t start
    uint32_t end

ctypedef vector[uint32_t] intvec
ctypedef vector[interval] interval_vector


cdef uint32_t start_end_equal(interval lhs, interval rhs):
  if ((lhs.start == rhs.start) and (lhs.end == rhs.end)):
      return <uint32_t> 1
  else:
      return <uint32_t> 0


cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    iterator unique(...)


cdef test(interval_vector intervals):
    intervals.erase(unique(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), start_end_equal))
```

The problem with the above code is that it errors with

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
  else:
      return <uint32_t> 0


cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    iterator unique(...)
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

minimal_example.pyx:21:4: 'iterator' is not a type identifier
```

Where can I find the iterator type to annotate my function?

Other workarounds also appreciated :)

(*) If you are wondering why I simply do not use `from libcpp.algorithm cimport unique` see [this related q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584909/unable-to-use-cdef-function-in-stdsort-as-comparison-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd answered this [in your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584909/unable-to-use-cdef-function-in-stdsort-as-comparison-function) since it came up in the comments. Posted here so this question has an answer (but community wiki so no reputation from the same thing twice).

Your options are to let the iterator type be a template argument (and just leave the function argument unspecified):

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    Iter unique[Iter](Iter, Iter, ...)
```

Alternatively you can restrict it to a specific vector iterator type as you've tried to do. In your case this is `vector[interval].iterator`. This is wrapped in Cython as a nested type inside the vector.